# Debugging on M1 Mac and Windows is different?

Tags: c++, windows, macos, debugging, apple-m1

I used two environments:

- (MBP) 2015 MacBookPro running Windows 10 on Boot Camp with Visual Studio Community 2022
- (MBA) M1 MacBookAir running macOS Ventura with QtCreator

And I got different results while following

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZO68JEgoPeg&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb&index=83

and trying to debug:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static size_t s_AllocCount = 0;

void* operator new(size_t size)
{
    s_AllocCount++; // BREAKPOINT AT THIS LINE
    cout << "Allocating " << size << " bytes" << endl;

    return malloc(size);
}

void print(const string& s)
{
    cout << s << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "starting..." << endl;

    string s = "bla";

    print(s);

}
```

On MPB the debugger stops at the breakpoint, as in the video.

But on MBA it does not stop. Why?

The following is the build output

```
19:59:22: Running steps for project project...
19:59:22: Starting: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.24.3/bin/cmake" --build '/Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/user/2024/projects/fasterstring/build' --target all
[1/2 3.6/sec] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
/Users/user/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/user/2024/projects/fasterstring/main.cpp:8:7: warning: 'operator new' is missing exception specification 'throw(std::bad_alloc)' [-Wmissing-exception-spec]
void* operator new(size_t size)
      ^
                                throw(std::bad_alloc)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/new:180:66: note: previous declaration is here
_LIBCPP_NODISCARD_AFTER_CXX17 _LIBCPP_OVERRIDABLE_FUNC_VIS void* operator new(std::size_t __sz) _THROW_BAD_ALLOC;
                                                                 ^
1 warning generated.
[2/2 6.4/sec] Linking CXX executable main
```

And later I tried:

- On MBP, instead of VS2022 still on Windows with MS compiler, used QtCreator which led to same result as of VS2022
- On MBA, installed Win11 on Parallels, and run VS2022. The debugger also stops, as in the video.

And finally, on MBA, tried VS Code which led to same results as MBA/QtCreator.

On MBA/QtCreator it seems both lvm and g++ compilers are available. Tried both but seems results are the same. Only debugger listed there is lldb.

I tried to install gdb and got the following:

```
brew install gdb                      
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
################################################################################################ 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
################################################################################################ 100.0%
gdb: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software.
Error: gdb: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

I'm about to conclude the environment for C++ development on M series Macs is not as good as Windows.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the compiler settings would be important here, e.g. which kind of debug symbols will be generated (I'm not in the best position to answer, but I'd start by comparing those).

Comment: Have you considered fixing the warning?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Please could you elaborate on this, should I look for those symbols on QtCreator?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, no difference.

Comment: What happens if you use a string that is longer than ~22 characters to initialize `s`? I forget the exact size of the short string buffer in clang. https://godbolt.org/z/TaMa1T5ce

Comment: Wow, then it works! So what's going on?

Comment: @KcFnMi Short string optimisation (see Google).  Kinda looks like MSVC doesn't have it, it's an implementation detail.

Comment: MSVC does have SSO (16 bytes) but when iterator debugging is on, such as in a debug build, there's an allocation for a proxy of some sort based on the name. With iterator debugging off there's no allocation.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That sounds like an answer to me